# Debian Jessie mysql-shell installation

Tags: mysql, debian

I am trying to install mysql-shell on a debian jessie distribution.
I have successfully installed and configure mysql-apt-config, then mysql 5.7 server.
I have followed instructions on mysql official website.
But apt is not able to find mysql-shell package.

Something strange was displayed during apt-get update:

```
Ign http://repo.mysql.com jessie/mysql-5.7 Translation-fr_FR                                                                                     
 Ign http://repo.mysql.com jessie/mysql-5.7 Translation-fr
 Ign http://repo.mysql.com jessie/mysql-5.7 Translation-en
 Ign http://repo.mysql.com jessie/mysql-apt-config Translation-fr_FR
 Ign http://repo.mysql.com jessie/mysql-apt-config Translation-fr
 Ign http://repo.mysql.com jessie/mysql-apt-config Translation-en
 Ign http://repo.mysql.com jessie/mysql-tools Translation-fr_FR
 Ign http://repo.mysql.com jessie/mysql-tools Translation-fr
 Ign http://repo.mysql.com jessie/mysql-tools Translation-en
 Ign http://repo.mysql.com jessie/mysql-tools-preview Translation-fr_FR
 Ign http://repo.mysql.com jessie/mysql-tools-preview Translation-fr
 Ign http://repo.mysql.com jessie/mysql-tools-preview Translation-en
```

I see this "Ign" prefix and download for each Ign line seems to by very quick. So i am wondering if apt-get install takes care of those repositories...

But, mysql 5.7 has been successfully installed...

Any Idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You needn't to worry this. In my opinion this operation need more time to connect with repository. When I ping repo.mysql.com I must wait 2-3 second to any respond. For you - I check this on my server. Take a look:

```
Answer for: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dists/jessie/mysql-apt-config`/i18n/Translation-en_GB.lzma
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: Apache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 16
Date: Sat, 17 Sep 2016 10:48:26 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

GET /apt/debian/dists/jessie/mysql-apt-config/i18n/Translation-en.lzma HTTP/1.1
Host: repo.mysql.com
Cache-Control: max-age=0
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.0.9.8.3)
```

If you check http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dist/jessie - you can find full path to any file and you can answer to your question. The server redirect to right path.

Comment: So what should i do on order to install mysql-shell ?

Comment: Any repository haven't package "mysql-shell". If you could do anything in mysql server you must do this:
`mysql -u root -p`

Comment: In fact I want mysql-shell for document store feature